# What does the term חתן refer to when talking about the relationship between two men?

Tags: non-blood-relative, translation, hebrew

I'm doing some genealogy research. Some of my ancestors are somewhat-known Hassidic figures. A few searches on Google yielded information in Hebrew and Yiddish that describes some of their dynasties.

What I can't figure out is the relationship between two men when someone is described as a "חתן" of someone else?

I know it's related to father-in-law and son-in-law but I can't figure out which one is which.

For example:

> יעקב היה חתן מאנדל
>   Jacob was the Chasan of Mendel.

I think this means: Jacob was the son in law of mendel.

And:

> יהודה לייב וחתנו אברהם
>   Judah Leib and his Chasan Abraham

I think this means: Judah Leib was the father in law of Abraham

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 4):

You are correct: the sentences you quote mean what you think they mean and, in general, "חתן" means "son-in-law". Be careful, though, because the similar word "חותן" means "father-in-law". Thus, "יהודה לייב וחותנו אברהם" would mean "Y.L. and his father-in-law A." although "יהודה לייב וחתנו אברהם" means "Y.L. and his son-in-law A.".

Source: My general knowledge of Hebrew; plus, [Nehemiah 6:18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt35b06.htm#18) has "חתן" meaning "son-in-law" and [Exodus 18:1](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0218.htm#1) has "חותן" meaning father-in-law. (The latter is spelled [defectively](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mater_lectionis), so it looks like "חתן" if you ignore the vowels. However, I think you can safely assume that people wouldn't spell it that way without vowels outside of Bible quotes/paraphrases, since it's so easily confused with "son-in-law".)

A tip of my hat to [Shalom](/users/4405/shalom) for the idea of citing the Bible, for one of those citations, and for the warning about defective spelling.

Comment: [Genesis 19:14](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0119.htm) : "and Lot went and spoke to his  חתןs , who had married his daughters" -- "chatan" = "son-in-law." [Exodus 18:1--2](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0218.htm) : "And Jethro, the *choten* of Moses ... brought Moses' wife." ("Choten" = "father-in-law.") If you don't have the vowels, it could be tricky.

Comment: by all means! And then I'll delete the comment.

Comment: Note also that Chatan and Kallah (groom and bride) refer to son-in-law and daughter-in-law.